# Why would changing a column from nvarchar to varchar result in substantial growth to the mdf file?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 15 million rows in it and I changed a column from nvarchar(100) to varchar(100).  This change is still is process (the change has run for about an hour now) and so far the mdf file has grown by 50GB (and it is still growing).

This was unexpected because a change from `nvarchar` to `varchar` should, in theory, result in a decrease in space used in the `mdf` (`nvarchar` requires about double the space of `varchar`).

Any idea why the `mdf` file is growing so much during this change?

---

**Environment: SQL Server 2014**

Edit: the cause is not due to autogrowth, as autogrowth is only set to 256MB.

Comment: If I were to venture a guess, I think it's because under the hood it's creating a new column and copying the data, leaving the space for the old data.  MDF files don't work like office documents, photos, music files, etc.  They often contain a lot of empty space and can be shrunk on occasion or automatically.

Comment: Probably I would have: 1. Created a new table with the desired schema. 2. Copied the data from the old table to the new table. 3. dropped the old table.  renamed the new table to the old table name.

Comment: Is it possible you have changed collation during the change?

Comment: @Afshin I made the change in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) in the Design view.  Other than this change to the table, there were no other changes made (like collation).  Thanks.

Comment: What happens after you shrink the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the change in SSMS Table Designer, SSMS creates a new table with your schema changes.  It then copies the data from the original table into the new table and drops the original table.  Finally it renames the new table to the original name.  The new table accounts for your .mdf file growth, assuming that the space needed for this exchange exceeds the amount of free space you have in your .mdf file(s).

If you start a trace on the server instance and then perform the steps to update your schema you can see all of the statements that are executed in the background by the table designer.

The process that SSMS does to change your column datatype is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.some_table (Col1 NVARCHAR(100)); --the original table

--SSMS does this in the background
CREATE TABLE dbo.some_table_1 (Col1 VARCHAR(100));

ALTER TABLE dbo.som_table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE);

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.some_table_1) EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.som_table_1 (Col1) SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Col1) FROM dbo.some_table');

DROP TABLE dbo.some_table;

EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.some_table_1', N'some_table', 'OBJECT';
```

You can mitigate this growth by using your own DDL instead of the table designer.  It's a trade-off - ease of automation vs. taking a while and growing your files.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.some_table ADD Col2 VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE dbo.some_table SET Col2 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), Col1);

ALTER TABLE dbo.some_table DROP COLUMN Col1;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.some_table.Col2', 'Col1', 'COLUMN';
```

You'll still get a little data growth because of the duplicated column data, but it'll just be a single column worth instead of the entire table.  Depending on the table it can make a huge impact.

Answer (score 1):

Because the database contains temporary work space and also holes after deleting records, the so called free space. Your conversion creates a new table and copies the data from the old table to the new table. This Free Space can be removed like this:

Once the conversion is finished, open Microsoft SQL Server Manager, right click your database and select

```
Tasks > Shrink > Database
```

See: [Shrink a Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) (Microsoft Docs)

Comment: This doesn't explains why it grew in the first place.

Comment: @Alejandro -- Yes, it does precisely that.